# ExpandebaleButton выдаёт ошибку в android studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема? Gradle проверил, версию AppCompat-а обновил, build clear и ребилд делал.

Сам код:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class News extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int NUM_EXPANDABLE_BUTTONS = 5;
    private LinearLayout container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.news_activity);

        container = findViewById(R.id.container);

        Button menuButton = new Button(this);

        menuButton.setText("*");

        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                expandButtons();
            }
        });

        container.addView(menuButton);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EXPANDABLE_BUTTONS; i++){
            expandebalButton = new Button(this);

            expandebalButton.setText("Кнопка" + (i + 1));

            container.addView(expandebalButton);
        }
    }

    private void expandButtons(){
        
    }

}
```

Сама ошибка:

```
error: cannot find symbol
            expandebalButton = new Button(this);
            ^
  symbol:   variable expandebalButton
  location: class News
```

Answer (score 0):

В самом методе onCreate нужно вписать `Button expandebalButton;`. Получается что-то вроде этого:     `@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); Button expandebalButton;`
Теперь компилируется.

Comment: Обьявить правильно переменную в Java -- это на ответ не тянет.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, на ответ тянет всё, что помогает решить проблему.